# Control two batteries with one switch?

Tags: power-supply, switches

I have a Raspberry pi and an amp circuit which both have different batteries/ power sources. I was wondering if it is possible to use a single switch to connect the two unified grounds to each of the grounds of the battery?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY00Kg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use a double-pole switch and you don't need to connect the batteries' grounds.

Comment: Even though the grounds are connected anyway? Sorry if that's a stupid question.

Comment: I edited your schematic to show more realistic voltage. THe question is have you thought about CMOS latchup with DC voltage difference on interface before power up. THis is a design violation if there is any shared CMOS connection.

Comment: What makes you think linking the grounds is disallowed? You can separate them if you are using optocoupler and relays to interact between the circuit then follow Brian's suggestion, or keep it as it is in the circuit and make sure you have driving transistors and diodes to prevent the 12v going back to the 5v.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you show is a bad idea.  With the switch open, there will be 7 V applied between the "amp circuit" power and the raspberry pi power.  Not only will that drain the batteries, but it could have strange consequences to either or both circuits.

Use a double-pole switch or two separate switches.

Another possibility is to create the 5 V power from the 12 V power.  Then you only need to switch the 12 V for on/off.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said it just to make things clear here's a diagram. What you need is a dual pole switch. This is a single mechanical switch with two electrically independent switches inside. The circuit then becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3k1DO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Search for DPST (dual pole, single throw) switch and you'll find plenty. You could alternatively use a DPDT (dual pole, dual throw) switch and not use half the terminals if that ends up being is easier to find.